# When would be the ideal time to take the Coastal Tram (Kusttram) so that you can actually sit down?

Tags: public-transport, belgium, coastline

I've been at the Belgian coast for some days now and I thought it would be fun to take the tram along the coast. But I noticed that it's always full of passengers. Now I'm wondering, is there a time that the trams are less filled?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest would be to get on the tram at the starting point of the line. You might also aim more for the morning than the afternoon.